# My friend's Dualshock 4 controller won't sync to my PS4

Tags: controllers, ps4

I'm doing some stuff with my mate's controller, but it won't even sync to my PS4. I did all the tricks and even bought a new sync cable, but nothing seems to work. Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: What "tricks" did you do?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

1. Turn on your PS4
2. Connect the DualShock 4 controller to your PS4 using the USB cable
3. Press the PS button on the DualShock 4 and wait for the controller to connect
4. Unplug the DualShock 4 controller and it should be synced with the PS4

Failing that, try the DualShock 4 reset button:

Turn off the PlayStation 4. Locate the small reset button on the back of the DualShock 4 near the L2 shoulder button. Use a small, unfolded paper-clip or something similar (but not a pin) to push the button (the button is inside a tiny hole). Hold the button down for a couple of seconds and release. Then follow the above steps again.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the usual plug controller into console, and reset methods. Neither of which worked for me.

Fortunately I have another controller that is still paired to the console. Using this other controller I logged into the console, went to

Settings/Devices/Bluetooth Devices

From here, I selected any devices not in use (those in use are displayed with a green light on the left, this should be the controller you're using) and pressed 'Options' and then 'Forget Device'. I then tried the plug in method again and it worked first time!